# Normal distribution statistics

Tags: statistics

please can someone help me do this: The average number of pounds (lbs) of meat a person consumes a year is 218.4.
Assume that standard deviation is 25 lbs and the distribution is approximately normal.If a sample of 40 individuals is selected, find the probability that the
mean of the sample will be less than 224 lbs/yr.